# Get first item of returning function value

Tags: python, tuples, argument-unpacking, kinterbasdb

I'm working with kinterbasdb module, and the module has this function called fetchone, that returns the result of an execution of a query:

```
cursor.execute("....")
cursor.fetchone()
```

This returns a tuple: `("value1",)`, and i want access the first item, but avoiding the `[0]` in the end, since doesn't tell much, it's a magic number. Is it possible? Perhaps some build in function?

I was trying to with:

```
value, _ = cursor.fetchone()
```

But this is returning: `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`, since the index 1 doesn't have anything.

Comment: Which version of Python? Does `value, *_ = ...` work? Also I wouldn't count 0 as a magic number in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with:

```
value, _ = cursor.fetchone()
#      ^ a variable with identifier _
```

is that it here **expects two elements** in the tuple you wish to unpack, but the tuple **contains only one element**. You can however solve this by writing a comma, but no variable like:

```
value, = cursor.fetchone()
#     ^ no variable
```

mind that you **have to write the comma `,`**: omitting it will *not* unpack the tuple.

or in case the number of elements in the tuple is unknown (but larger than zero), you could use the aterisk:

```
value, *_ = cursor.fetchone()
```

which will unpack the remaining elements in a tuple `_`. In case the expression has a tuple with one element, `_` will be equal to `_ == ()` (the tuple with no elements). In case you unpack for instance `(1,4,2,5)`, it will result in `value == 1` and `_ == (4,2,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the element using its index would be easier, hope it helps, I explained  this using a very basic  example :

```
def test_function():

return 1,3,4,5,6

#--- Getting function output using index ----#

print('',f()[0],' \n',f()[1],'\n',f()[2],' ..........')
```

result:

```
 1  
 3 
 4  ..........
```